# How to output logs to different Kafka topics under different keywords?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

Here is my Logstash input log file:

```
{"timestamp":"2019-10-18T16:37:53.137068+0800","flow_id":1072393101531249,"in_iface":"eno1","event_type":"event A"}
{"timestamp":"2019-10-18T16:37:53.137069+0800","flow_id":1072393101531249,"in_iface":"eno1","event_type":"event B"}
```

Now I want to output these logs to different kafka topics(`topic.A` and `topic.B`) based on different `event_type`.
Here is my current Logstash configuration:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/data/*.json"
  }
}
filter {

}
output {
  kafka {
    codec => plain {
      format => "%{message}"
    }
    topic_id => "topic.A"
    ...
  }
}
```

How can I do what I want in logstash filter and output?

Comment: Use [conditionals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals) in your output, for example, `if [event_type] == "event A" { output to kafka topic a }`

Comment: @leandrojmp You solved my confusion and I have implemented the function I want. Thank you very much.